# image recognition blackberry

Tags: blackberry, image-recognition

Hi i want to implement Image Recognition functionality on my blackberry application. Any one have idea which api can be used to recognize the image. I have used [IQEngine](http://www.iqengines.com/) Api on Android and IPhone but that api not supported on Blackberry.

Any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try MobileAcuity 's image recognition sdk for blackberry, I havent used it so I dont know how good it is. I have used their barcode scanning component and its pretty good.

Try it [here](http://www.mobileacuity.com/products.php)